# switch between player camera/non-camera positioning

Tags: java, 2d, libgdx

Sorry if this sounds ambiguous. But I am writing a traditional top down game.
And normally the player would be centered in the middle while moving the orthographic camera. However, I would like this to be dynamic. Therefore, use player.setPosition(x,y) near screen boundaries but center on player if its far from screen boundary.

This is some sample code:

```
public void centerCamOnPlayer() {
         camera.position.set(player.getX() + (player.sprite.getOriginX()),
                             player.getY() + (player.sprite.getOriginY()),
                             0);
}

public void update() {
     boolean shouldCenterOnChar = ???;
     if (shouldCenterOnChar) {
         centerCamOnPlayer();
     } else {
         player.setPosition(x,y);
     }
}
```

Therefore render will call update(). However how do I determine the shouldCenterOnChar?
I tried using frustum.pointInFrustum but its only when the sprite moves completely out of screen. I'm sure there is a better way to switch dynamically. Any one has an idea? Tks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably simpler to set boundaries on the camera set:

```
camera.position.set(clamp(player.getX() + (player.sprite.getOriginX()), 
                          minScreenX, maxScreenX),
                    clamp(player.getY() + (player.sprite.getOriginY()), 
                          minScreenY, maxScreenY),
                    0);
```